# Git - alterações locais de um arquivo no repositório remoto

Tags: git

Tenho um arquivo de configurações que existe no repositório remoto e no local, com informações para envio de e-mail.

No meu ambiente local, preciso modificar ele com as configurações da minha conta de e-mail particular para testes. Eventualmente precisarei dar push nas alterações que fiz locais, mas antes terei que alterar essas configurações do meu e-mail particular; 
Ou seja...
Na maior parte do desenvolvimento quero que as alterações desse arquivo não sejam levadas ao repositório remoto no push (somente as alterações dos outros arquivos), porém no final, posso precisar dar push nesse arquivo com algumas alterações pontuais.

Queria ignorar esse arquivo no push na maior parte do tempo, mas poder "designorar" quando eu quiser.

Pelo que li sobre o .gitignore, não é adequado pois serve para que todos os desenvolvedores ignorem o tal arquivo.

Eu tentei usar o .git/info/exclude, mas quando faço alterações locais,dou commit e push, as alterações vão pro repositório remoto do github...

Alguém pode me ajudar? Estou pulando alguma etapa?

Grato antecipadamente!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que você precisa é de um arquivo de configuração exemplo e ignorar o arquivo de configuração que está usando.

Não sei qual linguagem está usando, se quiser mencionar, posso editar a resposta.

Vou dar um exemplo em PHP

Crie o arquivo `.gitignore` e coloque o seguinte conteúdo:

```
config.php
```

Crie o arquivo `config.php.example` e coloque o seguinte conteúdo

```php
<?php
define('EMAIL', '');
```

Agora copie o arquivo `config.php.example` para `config.php`.
Edite o arquivo `config.php` e coloque seu email. Como o arquivo `config.php` está no `.gitignore` ele não será comitado.